# Try and except whilst trying to writerow in Python

Tags: python, json, csv, for-loop, exception

I have the following code that is throwing up an out of range error on the barcode looping section of the below code.

```
for each in data['articles']:
         f.writerow([each['local']['name'],
         each['information'][0]['barcodes'][0]['barcode']])
```

I wrote a try and except to catch and handle when a barcode is not present within the json I am parsing and this worked perfectly during testing using the print function however I have been having some trouble getting the try and except to work whilst trying to writerow to a csv file.

Does anyone have any suggestions or another method I could try to get this to work.

My try and accept which worked when testing using print was as follows:

```
   for each in data['articles']:
          print(each['local']['name'])
          try:
                print(each['information'][0]['barcodes'][0]['barcode'])
          except: 
                "none"
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What do you want to write to the csv when there is no barcode?  Do you want to skip that row completely, or write some kind of placeholder, or write a row that has the name but not the barcode?

Comment: I was hoping to have "none" when no barcode is present.

Answer (score 1):

As komatiraju032 points out, one way of doing this is via `get()`, although if there are different elements of the dictionary that might have empty/incorrect values, it might get unwieldy to provide a default for each one.  To do this via a `try/except` you might do:

```
for each in data['articles']:
    row = [each['local']['name']]
    try:
        row.append(each['information'][0]['barcodes'][0]['barcode'])
    except (IndexError, KeyError):
        row.append("none")
    f.writerow(row)
```

This will give you that `"none"` replacement value regardless of which of those lists/dicts is missing the requested index/key, since any of those lookups might `raise` but they'll all end up at the same `except`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dict.get()` method. It will return `None` if key not exist

```
res = each['information'][0]['barcodes'][0].get('barcode')
```